# can't play videos inside webView

Tags: android, html, video

Inside a webpage I try to open the following html and it works. As you can see it contains a list of videos. All this videos work perfectly when I open them inside my browser, but I fail to open them from my device. `Practically they don't play!!!!`
This is my webpage....each item is a link to a video...
[image: here is my image]

After I click one of this items I get here, this is the video...but it just doesn't play.

**IMPORTANT** The video doesn't play even if I click on it, whatever I do...it just won't play.
[image: here is my image]

And here is my code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("Here is set the link");
    }

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("Here is set the link")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            
        return true;
        }
        
        else{
            
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
   }
}
```

**IMPORTANT** The videos work inside of a browser. Anyone can give me a solution in order for my videos to play? Thank you

Comment: i m facing this same problem if you solve it then plz share it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `WebChromeClient` instead.

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    //Code here
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help. WebChromeClient is used with WebViewClient for showing progress update!